# "ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found" - class attribute

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm learning NodeJS and the task is to build a simple messaging service. The teacher is using SQLite3, but I decided to use Postgres since it's the DB we use in our company projects.

Error: "ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found"

```js
// server.ts

import 'reflect-metadata';
import express from 'express';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

import router from './router';

(async () => {
  const PORT = 3333;

  console.log('before');
  await createConnection();
  console.log('after');

  const app = express();

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  app.use(router);

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
})();
```

I have the following `MessagesService`

```js
// this works just fine
class MessagesService {
  async create({ user_id, text, admin_id }: MessagesCreateInterface): Promise<Message> {
    const repository = getCustomRepository(MessagesRepository);

    const message = repository.create({
      admin_id,
      text,
      user_id,
    });

    await repository.save(message);

    return message;
  }


  async listByUser(user_id: string): Promise<Array<Message>> {
    const repository = getCustomRepository(MessagesRepository);
    const messages = await repository.find({ user_id });
    return messages;
  }
}
```

Since `getCustomRepository` is called in both functions, and tried converting it to a class attribute:

```js
class MessagesService {
  repository: MessagesRepository;

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor');
    this.repository = getCustomRepository(MessagesRepository);
  }
  ...
}
```

But then I get `ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.`.

#### Experiments

1. Using a `setTimeout` inside `constructor`: The connection is accessed.
2. Consoles.log: I get "before" and "constructor" print, but not "after".

Can someone help me understand what's going on? As I'm using async/await, `MessageService` shouldn't be called until the connection was established. Am I'm breaking some pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `router.js` is being imported before `createConnection` is called on `server.ts`.

Since the controllers are instantiated inside `router.js`, alongside the services and repositories, they were indeed trying to access a database connection before it was created.

The solution I found is to lazily import `router.js` after the connection has been established, but I'm not sure if that's an anti-pattern.

```js
// server.ts

import 'reflect-metadata';
import express from 'express';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

(async () => {
  await createConnection();
  // Importing routes after connection has been established
  const router = (await import('./router').default);
  const PORT = 3333;

  const app = express();

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  app.use(router);

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
})();
```

The suggested way in the lectures was to create an instance of the controller inside every route, but it doesn't seem right to me.

```
router.js

// suggested way
router.post('/messages', (request, response) => {
  const messagesController = new MessagesController();
  return messagesController.create(request, response); 
});

router.get('/messages/:id', (request, response) => {
  const messagesController = new MessagesController();
  return messagesController.showByUser(request, response); 
});
```

Since I'm still learning NodeJS, feel free to correct me and point me to the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing to TypeORM the connection options so it doesn't know how to connect and setup the connection (which is the *default* one).

Calling `await createConnection()` without parameters will load connection options from files and (as far as I can see) you have not any *ormconfig.X* file.

To pass connection options to TypeORM you have three options:

1. *Connection Options Object*
   See https://typeorm.io/#/connection.
   Pass the connection options (object) directly when calling *createConnection({ ... })*.
   Example:

```js
const connection = await createConnection({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "test",
    password: "test",
    database: "test"
});
```

2. **ormconfig.X file**
   See https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig.
   Load an *ormconfig.[extension]* file in the project root.
   Supported ormconfig file extensions are: .json, .js, .ts, .env, .yml and .xml.
   Example (ormconfig.json):

```json
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "test",
   "password": "test",
   "database": "test"
}
```

3. *Environment variables*
   See https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-environment-variables.
   TypeORM automatically searches connection options in the environment variables or in *.env* or *ormconfig.env* in the project root (near package.json).
   Example:

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = postgres
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_PORT = 5432
TYPEORM_USERNAME = test
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = test
TYPEORM_DATABASE = test
```

Comment: Hello Carlo, thank you for the answer. I have a ormconfig.json and the connection is working just fine. 

I only get this error when trying to access it inside a class constructor.

Comment: I suggest [typeorm-typedi-extensions](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm-typedi-extensions). Simply use the @InjectRepository in your class. Easy as it is :)

Comment: Nice, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question has been marked as answered, but I had a similar issue recently(related to unit tests with mocha). the solution, in my case, was to stub typeorm `getCustomRepository`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm';
import {Connection, ConnectionManager} from 'typeorm';

describe('groupService', () => {

    let getCustomRepositoryStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        getCustomRepositoryStub = sinon.stub(typeorm, 'getCustomRepository');
        sinon.stub(ConnectionManager.prototype, 'get').returns({getCustomRepository: getCustomRepositoryStub} as  Connection);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sinon.restore();
    });

    it('findById returns empty result', async() => {
        const groupId: string = 'mock-group-id';
        getCustomRepositoryStub.withArgs(GroupRepository)
            .returns({
                findById: () => Promise.resolve([])
            });
        const groups = await groupService.getGroup(groupId);
        expect(groups.length).equal(0);
    });

    ...

});
```